# What is the best way to create a random fair hash function that can be replicated?

Tags: python, random, hash

The title probably sounds weird, but I'll explain what I mean.

Given k values, I want to map those to m buckets (m < k by at least an order of magnitude), such that each bucket contains either floor(k/m) or floor(k/m)+1 of the initial values.

Writing code to do that is very simple. The issue is, I want to be able to replicate the same distribution, by including something that makes the distribution reproducible in my code (something along the lines of a "seed"). Does anyone have any ideas how this can be done?

For the record, what I'm doing now in my Python code is selecting a random non-full hashbucket for every one of the k values, until all buckets contain floor(k/m) values. After this is done, I assign each of the values that I have left to a random bucket.

Comment: Could you share your actual code ?

Comment: If your current random solution is otherwise acceptable, then your "seed" is simply the seed of the random number generator you're using.  If that's still lacking in some way, we need to know what way.

Comment: It really sounds you want to use [`random.seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) (or its equivalent for what random module you are using).